# Netherland IPs on My USA Servers?

Tags: ip

I have servers with a lot of IPs /23 in the Netherlands and I want to use my IPs on my servers in the United States.

Can I do this without using any of my USA IPs?
I only have ns1 and ns2. Can both ns1 and ns2 nameservers use these IPs?

What is the basic process to set this up?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: This is not possible, at least not in practice. The IP's are tied to your dutch provider and can not be transferred to someone in the US (unlike DNS entries).

Which IPs you use for your DNS entries is entirely your decision, but you can not point any DNS entry to one of your dutch IPs and then expect the US server to handle the traffic.

BTW, this is one of the major advantages of the DNS system: Your clients don't need to care about IP addresses, just point them to a DNS name and if you have to switch providers, update the DNS entries and after the zones are updated, everything usually works without any config changes on the clients sides.

Comment: Assuming it's PA, not PI.

Comment: PI does not exist for smaller items anymore. Europe neve really gave them out. Smallest routable block is an AS with 4096 addreses international. And htat requires RIPE membership here. And multiple uplinks.

Comment: $Former_Employer had a /23 from RIPE.  Back in the day.